# android: How to cast values of varchar or integer type to real(float) type in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, casting

I have two columns. when i am dividing values of both table i am getting column of integer value. But I want the exact float values in the column after division.
One more query i have is that when i runing this query in shell its working fine but it is giving me error when i am using it in code. Please suggest some thing.

```
public ArrayList<String> selectQueryForcasting(Context context,String segment,String customer, String location)
        {   
            ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d("Inside Select ","Select starts for table name: Sales_Forcast");
            myDataBase = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Db",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);  
                            System.out.println("inside");
                                Cursor c= myDataBase.rawQuery("select ((Forecasted_Qty - Actual_Sales_Qty) * 100)/forecasted_qty from sales_forecast,customer,market_segment,org_location where market_segment.Market_Seg_Code="+segment+" and sales_forecast.Mrkt_Segment_Key=market_segment.Market_Seg_Key group by sales_forecast.time_key", null);
                System.out.println("Succcess"+c);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        z.add(c.getString(0));
                        //Log.d("EXAMPLE","string ");

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
                if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
                    c.close();
                }


            return z;
        }
```

Comment: You are getting strings in return yes? you may use Float.parseFloat("String here");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

select ((**cast(Forecasted_Qty as REAL)** - **cast(Actual_Sales_Qty as REAL)**) * 100)/forecasted_qty

or better yet:

select ((**cast(Forecasted_Qty - Actual_Sales_Qty as REAL)**) * 100)/forecasted_qty

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. Can you please tell me the problem with the query. it is showing me error

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. Can you please tell me the problem with the query. it is showing me error. myDataBase.rawQuery(..query..) as written in the code above. If i remove "where" part its working fine. Is syntax of where clause is incorrect. if there is any other alternative please suggest.

Comment: @neha If your segment variable contains non-numeric data, it need to be surrounded with single quotes, otherwise sqlite thinks you're trying to compare to another column. Try: where market_segment.Market_Seg_Code = '" + segment + "' and...

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
c= myDataBase.rawQuery("select ((cast(Forecasted_Qty - Actual_Sales_Qty as real)) * 100)/forecasted_qty,Mrkt_Segment_Key from sales_forecast,customer,market_segment,org_location  where sales_forecast.Mrkt_Segment_Key=market_segment.market_seg_key and market_segment.market_seg_code=? group by sales_forecast.time_key",new String[]{"+segment+" });
```